# Rails - Remove has_many relation when the parent is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models

**HiringTag**

```
class HiringTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :staffroom_id
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :hiring_tag_applications
  has_many :job_applications, through: :hiring_tag_applications

  after_destroy { |application|
    HiringTagApplication.destroy(application.job_applications.pluck(:job_application_id))
end
```

**HiringTagApplication**

```
class HiringTagApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hiring_tag, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :job_application
end
```

**JobApplication**

```
class JobApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hiring_tag_applications
  has_many :hiring_tags, through: :hiring_tag_applications
end
```

What I am trying to do: is when I destroy the `HiringTag` or `JobApplication`, I want the related data to be deleted in `HiringTagApplication` as you will notice I have a `after_destroy` inside `HiringTag` that call back does get executed but the error I get is:

> Couldn't find HiringTagApplication with id=96453

`96453` is not the `id` of `HiringTagApplication` but it is `job_application_id`

How can I correct this so the record can be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `after_destroy`, just use `dependent: :destroy` correctly like:

```
class HiringTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hiring_tag_applications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And

```
class JobApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hiring_tag_applications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

& remove it from associated table

```
class HiringTagApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hiring_tag
  belongs_to :job_application
end
```

Now, whenever HiringTag or JobApplication gets deleted its associated HiringTagApplication will also be deleted

Comment: Now, whenever HiringTag or JobApplication gets deleted its associated HiringTagApplication will also be deleted.